# Deedle: apply a function to Frame values

Tags: f#, deedle

I have a Frame containing several time series, and I need to normalize the values. Then, I need to take the first element of every Series, dividing all the element of the Series by it.
I tried with following code:

```
let normalize =
    MyFrame
    |> Frame.mapColValues (fun os ->
       let osAsFloat = os.As<float>()
       let firstItem = osAsFloat.GetAt(0)
       osAsFloat / firstItem)
```

but I have an error at: `osAsFloat.GetAt(0)`.
The only way I found is to convert values in single Series and, in a for loop, apply the function to the values.
There is a more functional way to achieve the same result?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
MyFrame comes from the next function, that downloads data from Yahoo! Finance:

```
let loadStocks symbols startDate endDate =
    [for symbol in symbols ->
        symbol =>
            let data = StockData.Load(urlFor symbol startDate endDate).Rows
            Series.ofObservations [for d in data -> (d.Date, d.Close)]]
    |> Frame.ofColumns
    |> Frame.sortRowsByKey
let MyFrame = loadStocks symbolList startDate endDate
```

and it's type is `Frame<DateTime, string>`

Comment: could you initialise MyFrame in your example with something sensible?

Comment: I added the code in the question. Thanks.